# What does this variable assignment do?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm having to code a subversion hook script, and I found a few examples online, mostly python and perl. I found one or two shell scripts (bash) as well. I am confused by a line and am sorry this is so basic a question.

```
FILTER=".(sh|SH|exe|EXE|bat|BAT)$"
```

The script later uses this to perform a test, such as (assume EXT=ex):

```
if [[ "$FILTER" == *"$EXT"* ]]; then blah
```

My problem is the above test is true. However, I'm not asking you to assist in writing the script, just explaining the initial assignment of FILTER. I don't understand that line.

Editing in a closer example FILTER line. Of course the script, as written does not work, because 'ex' returns true, and not just 'exe'. My problem here is only, however, that I don't understant the layout of the variable assignment itself.

Why is there a period at the beginning? ".(sh..."
Why is there a dollar sign at the end? "...BAT)$"
Why are there pipes between each pattern? "sh|SH|exe"

Comment: It matches, because the `es` is contained in the _test_.

Comment: The assignment simply assigns that string value to `$FILTER`. The piece you may be missing is that within `[[` ... `]]`, the `==` operator's right operand is treated as a pattern, not just a string.

Comment: Dollar sign (`$`) or ampersand (`&`)?

Comment: The three example scripts I found all show $'s. That is dollar signs.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the edit. I also realized that after I changed the example variable line I needed to change the assumption to ex vs es.

Comment: I ended up using a declared array instead of the regex. `declare -a filter_array`  `for elements_of_filter in "${filter_array[@]}"` and my compare was then `if [[ "$fileextension" == "${elements_of_filter" ]]; then` it worked for me and I understood it better. Now my hook script has log message verification, disallowed extension check and an override function. Thanks for the answers attempting to explain the regex, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably looking for something as next:

```
FILTER="\.(sh|SH|exe|EXE|bat|BAT)$"

for EXT
do
        if [[ "$EXT" =~ $FILTER ]];
        then
                echo $EXT extension disallowed
        else
                echo $EXT is allowed
        fi
done
```

save it to `myscript.sh` and run it as

```
myscript.sh bash ba.sh
```

and will get

```
bash is allowed
ba.sh extension disallowed
```

If you don't escape the "dot", e.g. with the `FILTER=".(sh|SH|exe|EXE|bat|BAT)$"` you will get

```
bash extension disallowed
ba.sh extension disallowed
```

What is (of course) wrong.

For the questions:

> Why is there a period at the beginning? ".(sh..."

Because you want match `.sh` (as extension) and not for example `bash` (without the dot). And therefore the `.` must be escaped, like `\.` because the `.` in regex mean "any character.

```
Why is there a dollar sign at the end? "...BAT)$"
```

The `$` mean = end of string. You want match `file.sh` and not `file.sh.jpg`. The `.sh` should be at the end of string.

```
Why are there pipes between each pattern? "sh|SH|exe"
```

In the rexex, the `(...|...|...)` construction delimites the "alternatives". As you sure quessed.

You really need read some "regex tutorial" - it is more complicated - and can't be explained in one answer.

Ps: NEVER use UPPERCASE variable names, they can collide with environment variables.

Comment: I have the full script. I know what it does, and in fact, I suspect that the original author has/had no idea his script does not work as intended. I get all that (I know I was missing code). What I did not understand is the variable assignment itself, the way it is laid out with the ".(... and the ...)$". Also the, I would call them pipes "|".

Comment: +1 because this is what the script *should* use; there is nothing to explain about the assignment itself; it's simply a regular expression stored in a variable.

Comment: @CGCampbell you should escape the "dot" in the regex, because the simple dot mean "any character" - see the edit...

Comment: @CGCampbell see the answer for your new questions.

Comment: Fully answered my question. My script still does not work, but now I have more of a clue than before.

Comment: @CGCampbell run your script as `bash -x myscript` - and you will see exactly what is doing. And after, make another question for other unclear parts.

Answer (score 1):

This just assigns a string to `FILTER`; the contents of that string have no special meaning. When you try to match it against the pattern `*ex*`, the result is true assuming that the value of `$FILTER` consists the string `ex` surrounded by anything on either side. This is true; `ex` is a substring of `exe`.

```
FILTER=".(sh|SH|exe|EXE|bat|BAT)$"
                ^^
                |
                +---- here is the "ex" from the pattern.
```

Comment: So the pipes "|" have no effect? I was also curious as to why the "." at the front and the "$" at the rear?

Comment: None. It's just data. If this were on the right-hand side of the `=~` operator, as [jm66 indicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25369962/1126841), then it would be interpreted as a regex, but on the left-hand side, it's just a string.

Comment: If `FILTER` actually has a `$` instead of a `&` at the end, then as a regex it would appear to match file names with one of 6 extensions, `.a`, `.b`, `.c`, `.d`., `.test`, or `.f`. But again, those characters have *no* special meaning in the context of the assignment itself. Only someone *using* the value of `$FILTER` would assign any meaning to those characters.

Comment: hmm, well, in that it is supposed to be a filter of disallowed extensions, such as my new example above, it's not working. I am planning on turning the filter variable into an array and work with it that way.

Answer (score 0):

As I can this is similar to regular expression pattern:

In regular expressions the string start with can be show with ^, similarly in this case . represent seems doing that.

In the bracket you have exact string, which represents what the exact file extensions would be matched, they are 'Or' by using the '|'.

And at the end the expression should only pick the string will '$' or end point and not more than.

I would say that way original author might have looked at it and implemented it.

Comment: Right (if I understand you.) that is what I thought. The way I was reading the example, it was supposed to test, let's say the string 'exe' against the filter line and it would be a true, which would block the resultant code. However, if I test 'ex' against the variable string, it is also testing true, and blocking code, even thought the variable string contains exe, any part of that is also testing true, such as 'ex' or 'xe'.